# How to manage multiple promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler using node.js. At first, I need to fetch the main page to get the URL of each item on that page, then I crawl URL of each item to get details of them one-by-one

`fetchPage(url)` is to get HTML text of a link

```
function fetchPage(url){
    return new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>{
            agent
            .get(url)
            .end(function(err,res){
                if (err){
                    reject(err);
                } else{
                    resolve(res.text);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

This is the global call of this crawler

```
fetchPage(link).then(
    (result)=>{
        const urls=getUrls(result);
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
            fetchItem(urls[i].link).then(
                (result)=>{
                    console.log('Done');
                },
                (error)=>console.log(error)
            );
        }
    },
    (error)=>console.log(error)
);
```

I processed to get the URLs of all items after fetching the main page (via `getUrls`)

`fetchItem(url)` is another `Promise` that ensures every HTML text of an item should be processed via `getItem` after being fetched by `fetchPage`

```
function fetchItem(url){
    return new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>{
            fetchPage(url).then(
                (result)=>{
                    getItem(result);
                },
                (error)=>reject(error)
            );
        });
}
```

It does crawl. It does get all items I need without any lack of information.

But there's something wrong with my code. Why doesn't the console log `Done` message for me?

Results are not in the right order. The order of crawled results is not as I expected, it is different from the order on the website.

Please point out what have I misunderstood and done wrong with these asynchronous control? How to ensure the order of them? How to fix this code to meet?

How should I do if I want to log a message `All done` after all items are completely crawled, making sure they're completely fetched in correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Done` is not getting called because you are not resolving the `Promise` created in `fetchItem` function.

I guess to maintain the order of results, you might want to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It will also help in getting `All done` message when all items are completely crawled.

I will start with changing `fetchPage` function by converting `urls` to a array of `fetchItem` promises using `map` that I can pass to `Promise.all`. Something like this

```
fetchPage(link).then(
    (result)=>{
        const urls=getUrls(result);
        var promises = urls.map((url) => fetchItem(url.link));
        Promise.all(promises).then((values) => { 
            console.log('All done'); 
            console.log(values); 
        }, (error) => { 
            console.log(error); 
        });
    },
    (error)=>console.log(error)
);
```

then adding resolve to your `fetchItem` method.

```
function fetchItem(url){
    return new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>{
            fetchPage(url).then(
                (result)=>{
                    resolve(getItem(result));
                },
                (error)=>reject(error)
            );
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you demo more specific with my code? Thank you